# I want the name to be stored so that when deleting the item, the item does not get renamed due to index

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When a new layer is added after pressing add layer button then new  layers are added for the box shadow generator. suppose I added 3 layers (Layer 1, Layer 2, Layer 3) when I delete Layer 2 after deletion the remaining Layers are Layer 1 and Layer 3 but Layer 3 gets renamed to Layer 2. I want Layer 3 name to be as it is. I know that the name are given through index so how can i change it?

```
import "./boxShadowGenerator.css";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export const BoxShadowGenerator = () => {
  const [boxShadows, setBoxShadows] = useState([]);
  const [selectedLayer, setSelectedLayer] = useState(0);
  const buttonRefs = useRef([]);

  const addBoxShadow = () => {
    const newBoxShadow = {
      hOffset: 0,
      vOffset: 0,
      blurRadius: 0,
      spreadRadius: 0,
      color: "#000",
    };
    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows, newBoxShadow];
    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
    setSelectedLayer(newBoxShadows.length - 1); // Select the latest layer
  };

  const removeBoxShadow = (index) => {
    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
    newBoxShadows.splice(index, 1);
    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
    if (selectedLayer === index && newBoxShadows.length > 0) {
      setSelectedLayer(0);
    }
  };

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    const boxShadow = boxShadows
      .map(
        ({ hOffset, vOffset, blurRadius, spreadRadius, color }) =>
          `${hOffset}px ${vOffset}px ${blurRadius}px ${spreadRadius}px ${color}`
      )
      .join(", ");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(`box-shadow:${boxShadow};`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (buttonRefs.current[selectedLayer]) {
      buttonRefs.current[selectedLayer].focus();
    }
  }, [selectedLayer]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="BSG-main-container">
        <div className="BSG-control-container">
          <h2>Box Shadow Generator</h2>
          <div
            className="box-preview"
            style={{
              boxShadow: boxShadows
                .map(
                  ({ hOffset, vOffset, blurRadius, spreadRadius, color }) =>
                    `${hOffset}px ${vOffset}px ${blurRadius}px ${spreadRadius}px ${color}`
                )
                .join(", "),
            }}
          ></div>

          {boxShadows.length > 0 && (
            <div>
              <h3>Layer {selectedLayer + 1}</h3>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`hOffset${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Horizontal offset:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`hOffset${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="-50"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].hOffset}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      hOffset: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`vOffset${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Vertical offset:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`vOffset${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="-50"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].vOffset}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      vOffset: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`blurRadius${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Blur radius:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`blurRadius${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="0"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].blurRadius}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      blurRadius: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`spreadRadius${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Spread radius:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`spreadRadius${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="-50"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].spreadRadius}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      spreadRadius: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`color${selectedLayer}`}>Color:</label>
                <input
                  type="color"
                  id={`color${selectedLayer}`}
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].color}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      color: e.target.value,
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="buttons">
            <button onClick={addBoxShadow}>Add Layer</button>
            {boxShadows.length > 0 && (
              <>
                <button onClick={() => removeBoxShadow(selectedLayer)}>
                  Remove Layer
                </button>
                <button onClick={copyToClipboard}>Copy CSS to Clipboard</button>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        {boxShadows.length > 0 && (
          <div className="box-shadow-list-container">
            {boxShadows.map((boxShadow, index) => (
              <button
                ref={(button) => (buttonRefs.current[index] = button)}
                key={index}
                id={index}
                className={`box-shadow-list-item ${
                  selectedLayer === index ? "selected" : ""
                }`}
                onClick={() => setSelectedLayer(index)}
              >
                Layer {index + 1}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

I want Layer 3 name to be as it is. I know that the name are given through index so how can i change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is a lot of text and logic to understand, but i think your problem is that u are using `newBoxShadows.splice(index, 1);` for deletion from array. Is is correct way but thats why u are losing indexes. Try `delete newBoxShadows[index]`. But be careful, because `delete` will not decrease length of array.

I can't understand what u mean by "Layer 3 gets renamed to Layer 2", cause your layers didn't have "names". But maybe these descisions will help:

1. save in `selectedLayer` not index but box shadow object by itself.
2. add in box shadow object `id` property. You will need an id counter for it.

Answer (score 0):

Add another state variable called `index`.
Add a key named `id` to the `newBoxShadow` object.

The value of the key should be the state variable `index`.

Now we need to increment the value of `index` every time the user clicks on add layer. Now use this index for displaying the layer name.

This way, even if the user deletes a layer, the index and layer name won't change.

Code:

```
import "./boxShadowGenerator.css";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export const BoxShadowGenerator = () => {
 const [boxShadows, setBoxShadows] = useState([]);
  const [selectedLayer, setSelectedLayer] = useState(0);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(1);
  const buttonRefs = useRef([]);
  const addBoxShadow = () => {
  
    setIndex(index + 1);
    const newBoxShadow = {
      id: index,
      hOffset: 0,
      vOffset: 0,
      blurRadius: 0,
      spreadRadius: 0,
      color: "#000",
    };
    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows, newBoxShadow];
    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
    setSelectedLayer(newBoxShadows.length - 1); // Select the latest layer
  };

  const removeBoxShadow = (index) => {
    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
    newBoxShadows.splice(index, 1);
    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
    if (selectedLayer === index && newBoxShadows.length > 0) {
      setSelectedLayer(0);
    }
  };

  const copyToClipboard = () => {
    const boxShadow = boxShadows
      .map(
        ({ hOffset, vOffset, blurRadius, spreadRadius, color }) =>
          `${hOffset}px ${vOffset}px ${blurRadius}px ${spreadRadius}px ${color}`
      )
      .join(", ");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(`box-shadow:${boxShadow};`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (buttonRefs.current[selectedLayer]) {
      buttonRefs.current[selectedLayer].focus();
    }
  }, [selectedLayer]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="BSG-main-container">
        <div className="BSG-control-container">
          <h2>Box Shadow Generator</h2>
          <div
            className="box-preview"
            style={{
              boxShadow: boxShadows
                .map(
                  ({ hOffset, vOffset, blurRadius, spreadRadius, color }) =>
                    `${hOffset}px ${vOffset}px ${blurRadius}px ${spreadRadius}px ${color}`
                )
                .join(", "),
            }}
          ></div>

          {boxShadows.length > 0 && (
            <div>
              <h3>Layer {selectedLayer + 1}</h3>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`hOffset${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Horizontal offset:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`hOffset${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="-50"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].hOffset}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      hOffset: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`vOffset${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Vertical offset:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`vOffset${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="-50"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].vOffset}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      vOffset: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`blurRadius${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Blur radius:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`blurRadius${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="0"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].blurRadius}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      blurRadius: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`spreadRadius${selectedLayer}`}>
                  Spread radius:
                </label>
                <input
                  type="range"
                  id={`spreadRadius${selectedLayer}`}
                  min="-50"
                  max="50"
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].spreadRadius}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      spreadRadius: parseInt(e.target.value),
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label htmlFor={`color${selectedLayer}`}>Color:</label>
                <input
                  type="color"
                  id={`color${selectedLayer}`}
                  value={boxShadows[selectedLayer].color}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    const newBoxShadows = [...boxShadows];
                    newBoxShadows[selectedLayer] = {
                      ...newBoxShadows[selectedLayer],
                      color: e.target.value,
                    };
                    setBoxShadows(newBoxShadows);
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <div className="buttons">
            <button onClick={addBoxShadow}>Add Layer</button>
            {boxShadows.length > 0 && (
              <>
                <button onClick={() => removeBoxShadow(selectedLayer)}>
                  Remove Layer
                </button>
                <button onClick={copyToClipboard}>Copy CSS to Clipboard</button>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        {boxShadows.length > 0 && (
          <div className="box-shadow-list-container">
            {boxShadows.map((boxShadow, index) => (
              <button
                ref={(button) => (buttonRefs.current[index] = button)}
                key={index}
                id={index}
                className={`box-shadow-list-item ${
                  selectedLayer === index ? "selected" : ""
                }`}
                onClick={() => setSelectedLayer(index)}
              >
                Layer {boxShadow.id}
              </button>
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```